# Use UISwitch to Hide UIViewContoller?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiswitch

Hi im currently developing an app where when you open the app a UIViewController with a PageViewController as a short tutorial. Im wondering if you could use the UISWitch to "Hide" that UIViewController so that the next time you start the app it goes straight to the "Main View"?

Thanks
PS. English is my second language.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to show it the first time, you don't need a UISwitch. Just use `NSUserDefaults` to remember whether you've run before or not.

In your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"RunBefore"]) {
    //show pagecontroller here
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"RunBefore"]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set an action for your switch:

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UISwitch *)theSwitch
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:theSwitch.isOn
                                            forKey:@"DontShowViewContoller"];
}
```

Then, next time, when you want to show the view controller you check:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"DontShowViewContoller"] == NO)
{
    [self showYourViewController]
}
```